# How to make the "delete button" not to delete the latest entry using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, row

My code delete the last row instead of deleting its own row, what to do?
i tried everything i can but it doesn't work please send help.

```
  $sql = "SELECT id, name, ArticleTitle, Article FROM article";

  if ($result = $conn->query($sql))
   {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr><td>" . 
    $row["id"]. "</td><td>"  ."<input type=hidden name=id value=". 
    $row["id"].">".
    $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . 
    $row["ArticleTitle"]. "</td><td>" .
    $row["Article"] ."</td><td>" .
    "<a href=connection.php id=".$row["id"]."><button>View</button></a>". "</td><td>".
    "<button type=submit name=login_user>Delete</button>" .


    "</td></tr> " ;
    // href="copytrade.php?id=$_GET['id']


}

echo "</form></table>";
```

and here is my **connection.php** script

```
 if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
      $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);

       if (empty($id)) {
        array_push($errors, "ID is required");
      }

    // sql to delete a record
     if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "DELETE FROM article WHERE id='$id'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only going to want one ID hidden field (currently you have one for every row). You'll set its value to the id of the delete clicked before submitting the form. The way you're doing it right now sends every id as the same value to the page via $_POST and the last one overrides all of the others.

Comment: and how to stop it from letting only one row to submit the data?

Comment: like if i pressed the delete button on row#1 with id#1 it will only send the value in the hidden input of the row#1 instead of sending the hidden input of the latest row?

Comment: Another way you could do it is wrap each row in a form and then each form would only have one id sent to delete.

Comment: that's exactly what i did sir! thanks for your answer tho!